# run tests on different environments like QA, Preprod

Tags: testrigor

How to run testrigor tests on different environments like QA, Preprod? I need to data driven the environment specific urls

Answer (score 3):

There are different ways to achieve that in testRigor.

1. Using different test suites, one per environment. One of the suites can contain the test cases and the others can be children of it inheriting the test cases.
   [image]
   [image]
2. On the same suite by using "branch testing". When you call testRigor via API you can trigger branch testing specifying with URL will be the target of the test. Detail of this can be found on CI/CD integration menu option within a test suite.